Show an Inequality $\int_{0}^\infty\frac{\sqrt x\ln(1+x+x^2)}{1+x^2}<(1+\sqrt 3)\pi$
Update
Thanks everyone in the thread answer me this question by evaluating the integral on the left explicitly, I really appreciate that!
But on the other hand, may I still request a method to prove this inequality without evaluating the integral explicitly? (For example, using some tricks for integral or write $(1+\sqrt 3)\pi$ as another integral of function $g(x)$ and $g(x)>\frac{\sqrt x\ln(1+x+x^2)}{1+x^2}$ for all $x$...?)

A few days ago, someone has asked me to do this integral
$$\int_{0}^\infty\frac{\sqrt x\ln(1+x+x^2)}{1+x^2}\mathrm dx\approx8.58193$$
I previously want to solve it by complex analysis (using contour integral) but failed... I first want to try the residues, and I divided $\pi$ for the numeral value, it is close to $2.7317\dots$ and I realize that the zeroes in $1+x+x^2$ and $1+x^2$ in the upper half in the complex plane is $\frac{1+\sqrt 3i}{2}$ and $i$, so this $2.7317\dots$ makes me think it is close to but a bit smaller than $1+\sqrt 3$. Is it a coincidence?
Also, may I ask here how this integral should be calculated besides the fact that the value is close to $(1+\sqrt 3)\pi$...?

Any way to use bounds or inequalities to prove the bound, since we don't necessarily need the closed form?

What kind of contour did you use? Here is one that should work.

I echo River Li's comment, in that all current answers focus on explicit evaluation, and not so much on establishing the inequality OP observed. I would suggest changing the title to reflect this, or to encourage numerical answers that demonstrate the bound.

@Integrand I have updated the problem description, but I would like to kindly and slightly push back from the suggestion of changing the title, since there has been quite a few answers here and if I do I may make the answers a bit deviated from topic.

Here is to explicitly evaluate the integral, via $\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(a^2+x^2)}{b^2+x^2}dx=\frac \pi b\ln(a+b)$
\begin{align}
& \int_{0}^\infty\frac{\sqrt x\ln(1+x+x^2)}{1+x^2}\overset{x\to x^2}{dx}\\
 =&\ 2 \int_{0}^\infty\frac{x^2\ln(1+x^2+x^4)}{1+x^4}dx
= 4\ \Re \int_{0}^\infty\frac{x^2\ln(e^{i\frac\pi3} +x^2)}{1+x^4}dx\\
= & \ 2\ \Re \int_{0}^\infty\frac{\ln(e^{i\frac\pi3} +x^2)}{e^{i\frac\pi2} +x^2}+ \frac{\ln(e^{i\frac\pi3} +x^2)}{e^{-i\frac\pi2} +x^2} \ dx\\
= & \ 2\pi \ \Re\bigg[e^{-i\frac\pi4} \ln(e^{i\frac\pi4}+ e^{i\frac\pi6} ) + e^{i\frac\pi4} \ln(e^{-i\frac\pi4}+ e^{i\frac\pi6} )\bigg]\\
= &\ \pi{\sqrt2}\bigg[\ln(\sqrt3+\sqrt2)+\frac\pi4\bigg]
\end{align}

Ah... so there is a $\pi$ here, and the value there is just a coincidence... Thank you so much!

The hardest part is the calculation on the second line from bottom. Nice solution.

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sqrt x\ln(1+x+x^2)}{1+x^2}dx=\int_{0}^\infty\frac{\sqrt x\ln x}{1+x^2}dx+\int_{0}^\infty\frac{\ln(x+\frac1x+1)}{\sqrt x(x+\frac1x)}dx=I_1+I_2\tag{0}$$
Using the keyhole contour in the complex plane
$$(1-e^{2\pi i})\int_0^\infty\frac{x^s}{1+x^2}dx=2\pi i\underset{x=e^\frac{\pi i}2;\,e^\frac{3\pi i}2}{\operatorname{Res}}\frac{x^s}{1+x^2}$$
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^s}{1+x^2}dx=\frac\pi2\frac1{\cos\frac{\pi s}2}$$
$$I_1=\frac{d}{ds}\,\bigg|_{s=\frac12}\frac\pi2\frac1{\cos\frac{\pi s}2}=\frac{\pi^2}{2\sqrt2}\tag{1}$$
$$I_2=\int_{0}^\infty\frac{\ln(x+\frac1x+1)}{\sqrt x(x+\frac1x)}dx\overset{t=\sqrt x}{=}2\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln(x^2+\frac1{x^2}+1)}{x^2+\frac1{x^2}}dx=2\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln((x-\frac1x)^2+3)}{(x-\frac1x)^2+2}dx$$
Using the Glasser' master theorem, or just making the substitution $t=\frac1x$
$$I_2=2\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln(x^2+3)}{x^2+2}dx=2\Re\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\ln(\sqrt3-ix)}{x^2+2}dx$$
Closing the contour of integration in the upper half-plane (where the logarithm does not have branch points)
$$I_2=2\Re\,2\pi i\underset{z=i\sqrt2}{\operatorname{Res}}\frac{\ln(\sqrt3-iz)}{(z-i\sqrt2)(z+i\sqrt2)}=\pi\sqrt2\ln(\sqrt3+\sqrt2)\tag{2}$$
$$I=I_1+I_2=\pi\sqrt2\left(\frac\pi4+\ln(\sqrt2+\sqrt3)\right)$$

Using $x=t^2$ $$I=\frac{\sqrt x\ln(1+x+x^2)}{1+x^2}\,dx=\int\frac{2 t^2 \log\left(t^4+t^2+1\right)}{t^4+1}\,dt$$
$$\frac{2 t^2}{t^4+1}=\frac{2 t^2}{(t^2+i)(t^2-i)}=\frac{1}{t^2+i}+\frac{1}{t^2-i}$$
$$\log\left(t^4+t^2+1\right)=\log(t^2-a)+\log(t^2-b)$$ where
$$a=-\frac{1+i \sqrt{3}}{2}\qquad \qquad \text{and}\qquad \qquad b=-\frac{1-i \sqrt{3}}{2}$$
If $\Re(c)<0$
$$\int_0^\infty \frac {\log(t^2-c)}{t^2+i}=$$ $$\frac{\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{i}{4}\right) \pi  \left(-4 \sqrt{-c} \tanh
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt[4]{-1} \sqrt{c}\right)+\sqrt{c} (\pi -2 i \log (1-i
   c))\right)}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{c}}$$ and
$$\int_0^\infty \frac {\log(t^2-c)}{t^2-i}=$$
$$\frac{1}{4} \sqrt[4]{-1} \pi  \left(2 \log (1+i c)+\frac{4 i \sqrt{c} \tanh
   ^{-1}\left((-1)^{3/4} \sqrt{c}\right)}{\sqrt{-c}}-i \pi \right)$$
Combining all the above, simplifying the complex numbers and using the logarithmic represntation of the hyperbolic tangent function
$$I=\frac{\pi  \left(\pi +4 \tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\right)\right)}{2 \sqrt{2}}$$

Via $\sqrt x\mapsto x $ transforms the integral into
$$
I=2 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^2 \ln \left(1+x^2+x^4\right)}{1+x^4} d x
$$
Via $x\mapsto \frac{1}{x}   $ transforms the integral into
$$
I=2 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left(1+x^2+x^4\right)-4 \ln x}{x^4+1} d x
$$
Averaging them gives
$$
I=  \underbrace{ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\left(x^2+1\right) \ln \left(1+x^2+x^4\right)}{x^4+1} d x}_{J} -4  \underbrace{ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln x}{x^4+1} d x}_{=-\frac{\pi^2}{8\sqrt 2}  \textrm{ by Beta function }} 
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
J& =\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\left(x^2+1\right) \ln \left(x^2\left(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}+1\right)\right)}{x^4+1} d x \\
& =\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left[\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^2+3\right]}{\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^2+2}d \left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right) +2  \underbrace{ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\left(x^2+1\right) \ln x}{x^4+1}}_{=0 \textrm{ by } x\mapsto \frac{1}{x}  }\\ & =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left(x^2+3\right)}{x^2+2} d x \quad (\textrm{ via }x-\frac{1}{x}  \mapsto x) \\
& =2 \Re \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\ln (x+\sqrt{3} i)}{x^2+2} d x \\
& =2 \Re\left[2 \pi i\left(\lim _{z \rightarrow \sqrt{2} i}(z-\sqrt{2} i) \frac{\ln (z+\sqrt{3} i)}{z^2+2}\right)\right] \\
& =4 \pi \Re\left[i \cdot \frac{\ln (\sqrt{2} i+\sqrt{3} i)}{2 \sqrt{2} i}\right] \\
& =\sqrt{2} \pi \ln (\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence $$
\boxed{\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x} \ln \left(1+x+x^2\right)}{1+x^2} d x  =\sqrt{2} \pi\left[\ln (\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})+\frac{\pi}{4}\right]}
$$
$$
$$

Feynman’s trick
Via $\sqrt x\mapsto x$ transform the integral into
$$
 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x} \ln \left(1+x+x^2\right)}{1+x^2} d x = 2 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^2 \ln \left(1+x^2+x^4\right)}{1+x^4} d x
$$
Differentiating the parametrized integral
$$
I(a)= 2\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^2 \ln \left(a(1+x^4)+x^2\right)}{1+x^4} d x
, \textrm{ where }a\ge 0.
$$
w.r.t. $a$ yields $$
\begin{aligned}
I^{\prime}(a) & =2 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{a\left(1+x^4\right)+x^2} d x \\
& =2 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\frac{1}{x^2}}{a\left(1+\frac{1}{x^4}\right)+\frac{1}{x^2}} \frac{d x}{x^2} \quad \textrm{ via } x\mapsto \frac{1}{x}  \\
& =2 \int \frac{1}{a\left(1+x^4\right)+x^2} d x
\end{aligned}
$$
Averaging the two versions brings us
$$
\begin{aligned}
2 I^{\prime}(a) & =2 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1+x^2}{a\left(1+x^4\right)+x^2} d x \\
& =\frac{2}{a} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}{x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{a}} d x \\
& =\frac{2}{a} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{d\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^2+\left(2+\frac{1}{a}\right)} \\
& =\frac{2\pi}{a \sqrt{2+\frac{1}{a}}}\left[\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{x-\frac{1}{x}}{\sqrt{2+\frac{1}{a}}}\right)\right]_0^{\infty} \\
I^{\prime}(a) & =\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{a(2a+1)}}
\end{aligned}
$$
Integrating back from $a=0$ to $1$ yields
$$
I(1)-I(0)=\pi \int_0^1 \frac{d a}{\sqrt{a(2 a+1)}}=\sqrt 2 \pi\operatorname{arcsinh{\sqrt 2}}=\sqrt{2} \pi \ln (\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})
$$
Hence $$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x} \ln \left(1+x+x^2\right)}{1+x^2} d x  & =\sqrt{2} \pi \ln (\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})+4 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^2 \ln x}{1+x^4}dx \\
& =\sqrt{2} \pi\left[\ln (\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})+\frac{\pi}{4}\right]
\end{aligned}
$$
Wish it helps.

Footnote for $I(0)$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^a}{1+x^4} d x
= & \frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^{ \frac{a-1}{2} }\theta \cos ^{\frac{1-a}{2} }\theta d \theta\\=&\frac{1}{4} B\left(\frac{a+1}{4}, \frac{3-a}{4}\right)\\=& \frac{\pi}{4} \csc \left(\pi\left(\frac{a+1}{4}\right)\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
Differentiating $I(a)$ w.r.t. $a$ at $a=2$ yields
$$
I(0)=4\left[-\left.\frac{\pi^2}{16} \csc \left(\pi\left(\frac{a+1}{4}\right)\right) \cot \left(\pi\left(\frac{a+1}{4}\right)\right)\right|_{a=2}\right] =\frac{\pi^2}{2\sqrt{2}}
$$
